# I want to create a new text file with C#

Tags: c#, file

I want to create new text files everytime the user clicks the button, so if the user clicks 5 times the button, I want make 5 new text files automatically. How can I do that?

Right now I have this but this doesn't work:

```
StreamWriter myOutputStream = new StreamWriter(@"C: \Users\LH\Desktop\test.txt");

foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
{
    myOutputStream.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}

myOutputStream.Close();
```

Comment: OK, so your code writes 5 lines to a text file... how is this related to making word files? what did you try in terms of making word files?

Comment: @BugFinder Evertime a user clicks the button i wanna make a new word file/document

Comment: @MohitShrivastava no

Comment: You will keep getting downvotes for such questions. Because 1) "this doesn't work" is a bad problem description. What exactly does not work? what did you expect to happen? 2) "I wanna ..." is not a real question. I am happy that you have such a strong will, but in a Questions & Answers forum you should rephrase your post as a Question. (As I am typing, I see that Garf365 actually took care of it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for

```
string txtFilePath = @"C:\Users\LH\Desktop\test";
int filecnt = 1;
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
{
    File.WriteAllText(txtFilePath + filecnt + ".txt", item.ToString());
    filecnt++;
}
```

This will create the number of TextFiles equals to the number of items in the listbox.

File naming will be like test1.txt, text2.txt etc...

Comment: YES, Thanks that is what i mean but it only gets the first value out the ListBox

Comment: Hi @daf32 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: It doesnt show all the values i have in my listbox only the first value.....

Comment: @daf32 come on you do need to do some of the coding yourself

Comment: I believe it should show one value in one file. @daf32. like First ListBox Item in First File and second ListBox Item Value in Second File. Hope this is what u wanted.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava o yes i see it now but your code also makes 3 TextFiles automaticlly even if i click 1 time

Answer (score 0):

You need have a naming convention / rule for your files.

For example: when using date and time you can use:

```
string filePath = DateTime.Now.ToString();
string content = "somecontent";

if (!File.Exists(filepath))
  System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filepath, content);
```

Put that code in your loop according to your specific scenario.

Remember, this is only if you want to use date time for filepath. You can use a counter, name list with counter, prefixes or suffixes, etc.

Comment: What do you mean with  content ?

Comment: content is what you want to write in your text file - the string value.

Comment: like this ?      string filePath = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            string content = "test";
            foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
            {
                if (!File.Exists(filePath))
               System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, content);
                myOutputStream.WriteLine(item.ToString());

            }
           
            myOutputStream.Close();

Comment: foreach (var item in listBox1.Items) { 
  string filePath = DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".txt"; 
  string content = item.ToString(); 
 
  if (!File.Exists(filePath)) 
   System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, content);
}

Comment: That should do it.

Comment: This is how my code is right now still crashes

Comment: Please elaborate. Simply stating that it is the same or crashes does not give any indication of the problem.

Comment: The specified padindeling is not supported.

Comment: If you have issues, simply google them first. Simply check your compilation error and debug afterwards once it is done building.

Comment: Look at your code above i edited it look if  it is what u mean

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure what you mean. But anyway, if you want to only want to do one of the items in the list per click, you have to keep track of the position in the list the last click processed. You need to figure out compilation errors by using the compiler. I can't help you with more than that.